# Exporting the projects in my solution file to another solution file

Tags: c#

I have included all my projects, about 42 projects in my solution so when I open the solution file it opens all my projects too,  now I have checked out another copy of SVN trunk and I would like to be albe to still use my previous solution file and open them all. So can I just copy-paste my solution file to the new folder that I have checked out code and open it? does it hurt the SVN fille? Is there a more native way for VisualStudio to do that rather than me copy pasting the file?
They look like this in the .sln file:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ucmkaryotypebuilder", "..\UCMKaryotypeBuilder\ucmkaryotypebuilder.csproj", "{77D441DF-5D4D-4F89-BE6D-594C18B46229}"
EndProject
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening your solution file would be illustrative here.  Most of the time, your solution structure is:

```
<root dir>
-- MySolution.sln
-- <project dir>
-----myProject.csproj
```

If that is the case, and your new checkout looks like this:

```
<root dir>
-- <project dir>
-----myProject.csproj
```

Then copying the solution file over should work.  That said, there is nothing to prevent you from having set up a very strange directory structure that wouldn't work, so you need to be careful of the relative path of projects vs. the solution file.

In a pinch, you can always make a new, empty solution file and use "Add Existing Project" to add them, one at a time.